# Passwording an external hard drive on Windows Xp/Vista

Tags: security, hardware, encryption, hard-drive

Was wondering if there is a way to protect the contents of an external hard drive on windows Xp/Vista?

Is it possible to password an external hard drive, such that when its plugged to a system, a password will be required to access it?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't say what OS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While not exactly what your looking for, take a look at [Truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/).  It doesn't have the "prompt for a password at plug-in" that your looking for, but it will do drive encryption.

Answer (score 1):

If it is going to be Windows 7 - you could try [bitlocker to go](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/enterprise/products/windows-7/features.aspx#bitlocker), though this is certainly not going to be acceptable for plugging into Linux, Mac or some earlier Windows installs either.

Personally, I would vote for [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) as well.